# How do I make a timer run in a Tkinter widget while a process, started by the widget, is running?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I used Tkinter to create a widget that allows the user to input some information and click the run button, which will begin running a test that is defined elsewhere. Here is the code. It is far from perfected, this is just a prototype:

```
from tkinter import*
import controller
root = Tk()
#create labels
label = Label(text = "text you don't need to know")
label.pack()
remind = Label(text = "more text you don't need to know")
remind.pack()

#create text fields
name = Entry(root)
name.pack()
name.insert(0, "Name")
name.focus_set()
testName = Entry(root)
testName.pack()
testName.insert(0, "Test name")
duration = Entry(root)
duration.pack()
duration.insert(0, "Duration in minutes")


def runTest():
    controller.main(testName.get(), name.get(), float(duration.get()))

#create run button
run = Button(root, text = "Run", fg = "red", width = 10, command = runTest)
run.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So, here is my issue. Once this project is implemented, the duration will likely be set for something like 1-4 hours. So, what I would like to do is have a countdown appear on the widget, so the users can reference that timer at any time to see how long until their data is produced. The problem is that as soon as my test is running, the widget locks up until it is complete. Everything I've tried is put on hold until it finishes running the test, then it does what I wanted. It doesn't help very much at that point.

Anybody have some experience at implementing something like this?
Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's up with Tkinter? I saw a flood of questions about it the past few days.

Comment: No idea. I knew almost nothing about it until I started implementing this part of my project today.

Comment: You have to run this test in thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fork off your work in `runTest`. The `threading` module will be your friend (e.g. `from threading import Thread`).

Then rewrite your `runTest` method:

```
def runTest():
    # pack your arguments in a tuple
    mainArgs = (testName.get(), name.get(), float(duration.get()))
    # create a thread object armed with your function and the args to call it with
    thread = Thread(target=controller.main, args=mainArgs)
    # launch it
    thread.start()
    #and remember, never set state (directly or indirectly) from separate threads without taking appropriate precautions!
```